# Error when trying to close an active Word document in c# application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, word-2010

I'm using c# with .net 4.0 Framework and Office 2010

I'm currently trying to figure out how to close an already open word document.
I'm running into an error with this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document d in app.Documents)
        {
            if (d.FullName.ToLower() == "OOPOR".ToLower())
            {
                object saveOption = WdSaveOptions.wdPromptToSaveChanges;
                object originalFormat = WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
                object routeDocument = false;
                d.Application.Documents.Close(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);

            }
        }
```

Currently, when I run this code, I cannot get into the foreach loop. the app.Documents shows a count of '0'. and if I set a break point at the foreach loop and look at the 'app' variable, it states:

```
ActiveDocument = '((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass)(app)).ActiveDocument' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' >> 
base {System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException} = {"This command is not available because no document is open."}
```

This occurs even though I have an active word document.

Comment: I just tested it and it was able to recognize the documents I have open, so it is something environmental.  Do you have the Office 2010 PIAs installed?

Comment: PIA's I'm no t familiar with that

Comment: PIAs are Primary Interop Assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx

Comment: Installing it now. I only had the Office API's installed for VS... I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: Negative, it's still throwing that same exception...

Comment: after rebooting the machine after install of the PIA, when debugging, I receive an error 
{"Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))"} 
I do not receive this error on running the application outside of debug. However, I do still get the same result of the document not closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my issue was stemming from a user vs admin conflict.

My application running with elevated privileges was unable to see the Word.Application and its documents running as a standard user.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~